# Wordpress site not showing after moving to server

Tags: wordpress

I'm kinda stuck with a wordpress site i'm building.I've moved the site from a local setup to a webserver and the **wp_options** are all set up right but i can't 
figure out why the site isn't showing on the server.

url: http://tinyurl.com/mlhck3b

Does anyone know what i've done wrong? thanks in advance!

```
function mbstring_binary_safe_encoding( $reset = false ) {
static $encodings = array();
static $overloaded = null;

if ( is_null( $overloaded ) )
    $overloaded = function_exists( 'mb_internal_encoding' ) && ( ini_get( 'mbstring.func_overload' ) & 2 );

if ( false === $overloaded )
    return;

if ( ! $reset ) {
    $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
    array_push( $encodings, $encoding );
    mb_internal_encoding( 'ISO-8859-1' );
}

if ( $reset && $encodings ) {
    $encoding = array_pop( $encodings );
    mb_internal_encoding( $encoding );
   }
}
```

Comment: there is some bracket is missing in functions.php file

Comment: I can't find any errors in the file using NetBeans, any other way i can check?

Comment: provide your file here.so i can check. Error is on line 4428.pl check once again

Comment: This is lines 4415 untill 4435:

Added it to the top.

Comment: Check if you have something like a root-meta-tag in one of your custom files. Setting this to a wrong uri would disable functionality.

Comment: Maybe it helps, but when i have the local apache server running the site shows.

Comment: It can't connect to the database... "Error creating the database connection". Check you're using the right details inside config.php

Comment: i only get "this page is not available". And i'm sure i have the right configuration

Comment: Lol, sorry guys, my collegue added the domain to the vhost settings. So i was going to the local server all the time :'). Sorry for wasting your time, but thanks a lot for your help!